# Antagônicos da palavra "genuíno"?

Tags: vocabulário, antónimos

Estou procurando por palavras antagônicas à palavra "genuíno" ou "genuinidade". Creio que a palavra "falso" seja uma delas, contudo, não estou certo.

Comment: Olá Matheus, bem-vindo ao site. Dependendo do contexto da frase, existem várias possibilidades. Pode ser mais específico?

Comment: falso/verdadeiro  Priberam diz: 2. Que não sofreu nenhuma alteração, adulteração ou corrupção. = AUTÊNTICO, LEGÍTIMO, PRÓPRIO, VERDADEIRO, NATURAL ≠ ADULTERADO, FALSIFICADO, FALSO

"genuíno", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/genu%C3%ADno [consultado em 03-05-2022].

Comment: @Rye, obrigado pelo comentário, procuro palavras que conotem o oposto de algo autêntico. Lambie, obrigado pela ajuda, era justamente isso que procurava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você procura é um [dicionário de antônimos](https://www.antonimos.com.br/genuino/):

> 1. contrafeito, deturpado, falso, falsificado, alterado, adulterado, corrompido, ilegítimo, ilídimo, inverídico, inautêntico.
> 2. defeituoso, errado, incorreto, imperfeito, inexato, invernáculo, viciado.
> 3. impuro, mesclado, misturado.
> 4. caviloso, fingido, desleal, dissimulado, hipócrita, insincero, mentiroso, pérfido, enganador, infiel, farsante, embusteiro.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Espúrio, adulterado, ilegítimo, apócrifo..